# I am trying to web scrape http://angel.co/bloomfire

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape data from a website https://angel.co/bloomfire

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://angel.co/pen-io')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

This prints with title tag as "Page not found - 404 - AngelList".
In webbrowser the website works fine, but its source code is not same as the output from my python script.
I have also used selenium with phantomjs, but it shows the same thing

Answer (score 3):

It looks like angel.co will respond with an `HTTP 404` based on the `User-Agent` that is sent, and it looks like it will block the default `requests` agent (possibly depending on version). This is likely to discourage bot activity.

Some output from my `ipython` session follows. I'm using `requests/2.17.3`.

#### Using default Python-requests User-Agent

```
In [37]: rsp = requests.get('https://angel.co/bloom')
In [38]: rsp.status_code
Out[38]: 404
```

#### Using a Mozilla-compatible User-Agent

```
In [39]: rsp = requests.get('https://angel.co/bloom', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

In [40]: rsp.status_code
Out[40]: 200
```

`rsp.content` contains the content you'd expect to see from angel.co/bloom.

#### Using some random User-Agent

```
In [41]: rsp = requests.get('https://angel.co/bloom', headers={'User-Agent': 'birryree angel scraper'})

In [42]: rsp.status_code
Out[42]: 200
```

---

So you should be setting the `User-Agent` to get past any kind of filtering/blocking angel is using for various default agents.

If you're going to be doing heavy scraping, I'd suggest you be a good citizen and set an agent string that would let them contact you in case your scraping is causing issues, like:

```
requests.get('https://angel.co/bloom', 
             headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; http://yoursite.com)'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding headers to the requests parameter you can reach the page. Here is the results for "PEOPLE ALSO VIEWED". Try the below script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://angel.co/pen-io', headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for item in soup.select(".text"):
    try:
        title = item.select_one("a.startup-link").get_text()
    except:
        title = ''
    print(title)
```

Results:

```
Corilla
Pronoun
checkthis
Wattpad
Medium
Plympton
Cheezburger
AngelList
```